# How can I convert 24 bit. 48000HZ .wav to 8 Bit 8000HZ .wav without noise?

Tags: audio, converters

I can´t get this audio clean, So I don´t now what to do. I hace tried cleaning it, Transforming on various kinds of formats.

Comment: Writing a program to do this might in theory involve programming questions that are on topic, but for now this is entirely off-topic.

Comment: 8 bit audio has a noise floor at -48dB. Is the converted noise floor higher or perhaps you are mistaking distortion for noise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in [this](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23032/what-is-the-proper-way-to-reduce-audio-sample-rate-and-bit-depth). Generally [Dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Digital_audio) may be important in your case.

Maybe these settings help you for starting:

```
sox input.wav -b 8 output.wav gain -1 rate 8000 dither -s
```

Answer (score 0):

Open this sound in Audacity, convert to 80 kHz and apply noise filter on correct level.